# How can I delete the reference in a many to many relationship without deleting the entity in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make a spring application where you can like and unlike a game. I have a ManyToMany relationship between the player and the game. I have made it so that when a player likes a game it adds that relationship to the linking table and I when a player unlikes a game I want to delete that relationship. I have read other stackoverflow questions where they say to just delete from respective list. The thing is that only doing this doesn't work becuase the database needs to be updated. Something i can use is `playerRepository.delete(player)` but this deletes the reference AND the player which isn't what I want. I want to only delete that reference.

Player class:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "game_like", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"))
private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
```

Game class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "games")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
```

PlayerController:

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "api/v1/player/{id}/unlove")
public void unloveGame(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Game game) {
    Player player = playerRepository.findById(id).get();
    game.removePlayer(player);
    player.removeGame(game);
    playerRepository.delete(player);

}
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I have also tried using `playerRepository.save(player)` but that doesn't work either. I have also read that using `CascadeType.remove` is not recommended for many to many relationships

Comment: define a `CASCADE` policy on the relation, and then you only need a `save` or `merge` instead of `delete`

Comment: Do you really NEED a manytomany relationship here? If it is a successful system you potentially get millions of likes on a game which will all be tanked into the entity when touched even if you likely don't need that data at all, probably only a total count. I would personally just create an entity for the join table in this particular case.

Comment: @Gimby so you mean to create a new entity like the player and the game so that i also get a repository and other stuff for it?

Comment: GameLike, yes. Granted I haven't given much thought to the design but my first gut feeling is that I would probably not go with a manytomany here; I only use those when they are going to functionally be useful in the code.

Comment: But wont it be the same thing except I can do more stuff with the table?